# How to use custom xamarin.forms library

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

I have downloaded the official xamarin.forms library from [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms). I edited some of the main library class and now I want to use that into a project instead of the common one through NuGet package. How can I do that?

Comment: remove the Nuget package and reference your local copy via project references, like you would with any other library

Comment: I am not sure how to reference my copy, because when i go to "Edit NuGet package" i can only add official package in Browse section, I can't see where I can add custom package from a local path

Comment: just reference the local dll, not the nuget package.  If you want to use the custom nuget package, you will need to add a new source to your nuget properties

Comment: I thing I did that, in Configure Sources I added the path of the folder that I downloaded from Github, but when I try to use that source there are no package shown on the Browse list

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure I understand, because what I downloaded is the whole code of Xamarin.Forms, in which I edited some of the main common classes (like View.cs), and i don't thing this is a NuGet package

Comment: YOU are the one who keeps insisting on using Nuget.  I recommended that you just reference the dll directly in the project references.  Do you not understand how to do that?  In VS Mac, right click on "Dependencies" and select "Add Reference".  It may be a little different on VS Windows.

Comment: But I don't have the dll either in what I downloaded, I just have lots of Classes and I edited some of them, inside Xamarin.Forms.Core. Sorry for my ignorance but I am new to that environment

Comment: you BUILD your modified copy of the project to generate the DLL.  To be blunt if you don't understand these basic C# concept you really shouldn't be attempting to modify the source of XF

Comment: I know sorry but basically I have been left alone with that project only few days after I started learning Xamarin. Thanks for your help

Comment: keep in mind that using a modified copy of Forms means that you will not get the benefits of bug fixes and new features added to the official XF unless you are willing to spend the time to continually update your copy.  Also, what sorts of changes are you making, and why?  Are you sure there is not a better way to meet your goal?  I've been using XF for years and have never had the need to hack up my own copy of the library.

Comment: Ok thanks i'll keep in mind. Basically I need to find a way to reproduce a sound when an element receive the Accessibility Focus, instead of reading his AutomationProperties name. So I thought I needed to find a way to use the isAccessibilityFocused() of Android and iOS in XF and my professor (who is also new to that environment) suggested to modify the constructor of the View class and then use dependency services.